# Washer Machine Fix

Tags: transistors

Final Update: See the final 2 images.  Currently running a load of laundry.
Transistor: NPN - 2222A
Relay: Universal Dorman Automotive Relay
Battery: 9V Duracel
The double capacitor volt reduction didn't work. (Image 6 using 10k ohm top and 1k ohm bottom)
Thoughts?

Original Post:
What transistor would work with 14.5v @ 1mA to Base, 9V Battery (+) Collector, Emitter to Relay (Prong 85), Relay Prong 86 to 9V Battery (-).  See diagram below.

I have a washing machine PCB that is on its last limb.  The new machine is on it's way, but still a month away from delivery.  The problem is the drain pump won't drain the water.  The pump itself is fine.  Initially I thought it was the relay that was bad, so I removed it.  However after further inspection I discovered that the low level current being sent to the relay is severely low.  Whatever component that sends that low voltage (14.5v) signal to the relay is damaged.  It still sends 14.5v as expected, but only 1mA (milliAmp).  I measured with a multimeter.  This is not enough to energize even a small relay.  14.5v x 1mA = 14.5mW  I believe that is correct.  The spec sheet on the relay says it needs 200mW for its coil to activate the relay, so we are not even close to that with only 14.5mW.

After removing the relay, I soldered on 4 wires to the PCB to where the relay connected.

2 wires for low level current (14.5v) the signal.

2 wires for the high level current (~150v) this is the completion of the positive current for the drain pump.

I've replaced the relay that I removed with an automotive relay.  The high level current connects to 30 and 87 just like on the previous relay.  For 85 and 86 however, I've wired in a 9V battery and a toggle switch.  9V positive goes to toggle then to 85.  86 goes to 9V negative to complete the circuit.  When I turn the toggle switch on it activates the drain pump.  Yay!

This is an ok solution for the next month, but I was hoping you could help me identify a transistor that might work in place of the toggle switch.  The Base would be powered by the 14.5v   1mA   low level current from the PCB.  The collector would be attached to the 9V battery positive.  The emitter would be attached to 85 on the relay.  And finally 86 on the relay would be attached to the negative 9V battery.

As of now, I have to Homer Simpson style manual override the drain pump 3 times per wash cycle.  A transistor would be helpful if you think it would work with the given power levels.

Washer Repair:
[image]
What I have:
[image]
What I want:
[image]
Updated Diagram:
[image]
Top 2 wires are high voltage (Relay prongs 30 & 87) Bottom 2 wires are the low voltage signal to activate the relay (Relay prongs 85 & 86).
[image]
Updated diagram with a voltage drop.
[image]
This ended up working: (currently running)
[image]
Actual Implementation (the toggle switch is no longer connected):
[image]

Comment: Can you see them now as html img links?  Copy paste was not working, it was saying over 2MB, but the images are all 515KB each.  Upload was not working, but Imgur could not be contacted.

Comment: Your 9V battery isn't going to last very long driving a relay coil. And the automotive relay isn't rated for switching line voltage.

Comment: Basically any cheap NPN transistor. You do need to learn how to wire it correctly though.

Comment: Going to try something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=getN1wMYSXY  Maybe using this NPN transistor:  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjrx7Sd3afrAhXhhHIEHf9XBS0QFjABegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fdatasheet%2Fcd00003223.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3MzCKC3SLiUYW_FOVw10cW

Comment: What happens if you try to take more than 1mA from that 14.5V output?

Comment: https://www.nteinc.com/specs/100to199/pdf/nte199.pdf   Looks like I need to lower my 14.5V down to 5V.  Would a resistor at the base prong accomplish that?  Which resistor would get it down to 5V?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: This seems a bit hacky. Whats upstream of the old relay? Another transistor? Resistor? Anything? If the old relay works why not use that instead of the automotive relay? The auto relay may not like 150V AC.

Comment: In any case, that circuit won't work as there's no return path for the current coming from that 14.5V output.

Comment: Thank you Finbarr.  What if I connected BOTH the 14.5V positive AND negative to the Base prong?  I think that's what I need to do.  Passerby, yes this is very hacky.  Upstream of the relay are tiny components with a burn mark.  So tiny I don't even want to mess with them.  Probably resistors.  Anyways, it just is a fun experiment until the new washer comes in.  If I can't get the transistor to work, the manual switch will work just fine... I just have to activate it 3x per wash load.  What resistor do I use to get the 14.5v down to 5V?

Comment: No, that will just short out your 14.5V. Just get a switch rated for mains voltage and sufficient current and use it in place of the relay.

Comment: I would suggest replacing the relay with the right one.  Your comment "I see the 14.5V but only 1mA" may be true, but note it's not necessarily the SOURCE that limits to 1mA, it's the LOAD that effectively determines how much current flows.  In other words, you're probably blaming the wrong component.  If the relay coil is kaput, it would be presenting an unusually high resistance, which would cause a lower current to flow  (Ohms law -   V=IR...  If R goes up, V is constant, I must go down)

Comment: Finbarr, when you say switch, I don't know what you mean (toggle switch?)  Can you provide a link or example?

Comment: Yes, a toggle switch, just like the one you've already used but rated for the pump voltage and current. The rest of all this is pointless.

Comment: Finbarr, what you are suggesting does not automate washing a load of laundry.  I'd still have to flip the switch 3 times per load.  There are 3 drain cycles per load, which means I need to stand there 3 separate times to manually drain the water.  I'm certain with the collective knowledge of master EE's there is a solution to automate this process with the 14.5v @ 1mA signal that I get from the PCB when the drain cycle is activated.  The problem is that that signal was originally 14.5 @ 15mA and was enough to activate a relay..... now it is not enough.  Make a transistor work here.

Comment: @james those burned components are likely a diode resistor and transistor already. Trying to use the 14v 1mA through the burned parts is risking fire or more damage.  Either bypass and or replace them. Did you look for a service manual for the washer? Likely has a schematic.

Comment: Do you have Vcc (12-15 V) available? An emitter follower should do the trick for you.

Comment: See updated diagram (4th image).

Comment: Indeed better, but why are you set on using a battery? Find Vcc somewhere and use that. Depending on the relay coil current, 9 V may be too low to start with and many not supply enough current due to internal resistance.

Comment: M.ic.k.e.y ...m.o.u.s.e. This is not hard. Lookup NPN switch for low side

Comment: Winny, because I don't know what Vcc is or where to find it on that board. See the 5th image.  The board is all covered in a gel to protect the board from moisture.  Hunting for Vcc would require more gel removal.  The 9V battery energizes the relay and I know it works.  Again, this is a stop-gap solution only to last 1 month.  I'm ok with it being hacky.  I'm more interested in learning how to use transistors and resistors here.

Comment: I'm going to use a PN2222 transistor.  I think I have to do a voltage drop from 14.5v to 5v for the Base prong.  Also I think I only need 0.1mA at the base.  I think the relay 85 to 86 is drawing ~15mA.  What 2 resistors would you use here to get that voltage and amp drop?   And where would you put them?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112022/discussion-on-question-by-james-b-washer-machine-fix).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.  It's working.

Comment: Impressive! Your wife must be really understanding.

Comment: lol she is.  the new washer will be here in a month.  I’m happy to report that it did 2 loads thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Mosfet would be a solution since you cannot provide many amps.

Transistors work using current to turn on.

Mosfets use just voltage (and currents like some nAmp or uAmp). Thats why mosftets sometimes get activated when touching them. They are sensitive to anything.

And using a mosfet would also not require a Resistor since you dont want to limit the current it draws. (But i suggest you put one resistor anyway on the gate (aka Base))

Also, you should use a flyback diode as @csabahu recommended, or else you may fry your mosfet or transistor in no time (it may not last a day)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, it will probably work:
[image: mosogep]

Comment: Thank you csabahu.  I understand the diode additions to protect the components, but this is only to last 1 month so I don't really care about ruining the transistor or relay.  I tried a 10k top and 1k bottom resistor and it didn't work.  Perhaps it wasn't enough voltage.  Anyways, I read the base to emitter voltage in the final diagram as 4.5v so that seems good.

Comment: The base emitter voltage is could be max. 0.7V, as long as the transistor is good. If there is 4.5V, it is either badly connected or already faulty.

Comment: "I don't really care about ruining the transistor" This is not like runining it in years. If you're unlucky enough, it will work 5 times and stop. Do you want to be replacing the transistor every 5 washes? Probably not :)